# Eigenvector for a non-linear system

Tags: dynamical-systems, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

> Using the reversibility arguments alone, show that the system
>
> $\dot{x}=y$
>
> $\dot{y}=x-x^{2}$
>
> has a homoclinic orbit in the half-plane $x\leq 0$

This is a non-linear system.

A linear approximation requires the Jacobian:

$J=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
1-2x &0 
\end{bmatrix}$

The fixed points are $(0,0) \text{and} (1,0)$.
It is easy to check that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

> Mathematica gives the Eigenvalues:
>
> $\left\{\left\{\lambda \to -\sqrt{1-2 x}\right\},\left\{\lambda \to \sqrt{1-2
>    x}\right\}\right\}$

There doesn't seem to be any reliable way, at least to the best of my knowledge, to determine the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for these sort of crazy non-linear examples.

It doesn't help that in the text "Nonlinear dynamics and Chaos" by Strogaz
the explanation is as

> "Consider the unstable manifold of the saddle point at the origin, The manifold leaves the origin along the vector $(1,1),\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Can someone assists me with determining the Eigenvectors? It is giving me a lot of problems.

Comment: There is no homoclinic orbit in the half-plane $x\leqslant0$. To find the homoclinic orbit in the half-plane $x\geqslant0$, note that $y(x)y'(x)=x-x^2$ along every orbit hence the orbits are $y^2=x^2-\frac23x^3+c$ and the desired homoclinic orbit has equation $y=\pm x\sqrt{1-\frac23x}$, $x\geqslant0$,

Comment: @Did Can the eigenvectors not be found? The stability of the manifold is always associated with the eigenvectors.

Comment: ?? Yes the eigenvectors "can be found", and so what?

Comment: @Did 
Can you tell me why the unstable manifold leaves the origin along the vector (1,1)?

Comment: This is the eigenline for the positive eigenvalue.

Comment: I assume Eigenline is another word for eigenvector-otherwise, please correct me. 
The positive eigenvalue has an associated eigenvector of $\left \langle 1,+\sqrt{1-2x} \right \rangle$.
I'm curious to know how all these piece together with the vector$ \left \langle 1,1\right \rangle$ and the unstable manifold. 
Big picture works best.If you would give me a verbose explanation I'll be really thankful! @Did

Comment: No, eigenline is a line while eigenvector is a vector. // If one is looking at the unstable eigenline at $(0,0)$, wouldn't it be wise to note that, when $(x,y)=(0,0)$, the eigenvector $(1,\sqrt{1-2x})$ for the positive eigenvalue $\lambda=\sqrt{1-2x}$ becomes... yes, $(1,1)$. Do you understand that one only uses the Jacobian matrix and its eigenvalues, at the fixed points?

Comment: @Did No.
I understand that the Jacobian provides a linear approximation to a non-linear system. Easily, the eigenvalues of the Jacobian at the fixed points can be determine-easy enough.
The problem I face is the saddle point. The saddle point has a stable and unstable manifold. From what I gathered from the author's rather causal remark is Eigenvectors are necessary to determining which manifolds are stable and which are unstable. Unstable manifolds has traj pointing away from the saddle point.@Did

Comment: All this seems to be pointing at the conclusion that you first and foremost need a serious textbook on the subject. What is yours?

Comment: The text is"nonlinear dynamics" by Strogaz.@Did
I enjoy dynamical systems but the book doesn't quite go too much in depth. It provides the idea but as a final year undergraduate how much is enough?
I have easy access to "Chaos, an introduction to dynamical systems" by Alligood.@Did

Comment: @Did I made the note that at (x,y)=(0,0), we get (1,1). That came with a bit of intuition but yet without understanding whether it was the 'right' thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=-\sqrt{1-2x},\ \lambda_2=\sqrt{1-2x}$.

To find the eigenvalues, you need to solve $(A-\lambda I)v=0$.

$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{1-2x} & 1\\
1-2x & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
v_1=0$$

**(a)** Letting $v_1=\left[
\begin{matrix}
v_1^{(1)}\\
v_1^{(2)}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]$, we see that $$\sqrt{1-2x}v_1^{(1)}+v_1^{(2)}=0,$$ giving us $$v_1^{(2)}=-\sqrt{1-2x}v_1^{(1)},$$ and we see that the first eigenvector $v_1$ is 
$$v_1=\left[
\begin{matrix}
1\\
-\sqrt{1-2x}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$ up to scalar multiplication.

**(b)** Similarly, $v_2$ satisfies $$\left[
\begin{matrix}
-\sqrt{1-2x} & 1\\
1-2x & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]v_2=0,$$ yielding $$v_2^{(2)}=\sqrt{1-2x}v_2^{(1)},$$ showing that the second eigenvector is $$v_2=\left[
\begin{matrix}
1\\
\sqrt{1-2x}\\
\end{matrix}
\right].$$

Essentially you find them the same way you would a linear system.